# css ribbons not displaying right in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My two ribbons I have for titles in the sidebar are not displaying in any IE version right.
The right bottom flap that gives it the wrap around look is not showing up. It's almost like IE does not like the before and after CSS thing.

Link
http://tshirthideout.spreadshirt.com/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ribbon"><strong>SPECIAL OFFERS</strong></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ribbon {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #c1c1c1;
  font-size: 15px;font-family:'Century Gothic',futura,'URW Gothic L',Verdana,sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  position:relative;
  width:267px;
  right:0px;
  top:19px;
  background-color:#212121;
  -moz-border-radius:2px 0px 0px 2px;  /*radius of 2px*/
  -khtml-border-radius:2px 0px 0px 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius:2px 0px 0px 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
  -moz-box-shadow:    -2px 2px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
  box-shadow:         -2px 2px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
}

.ribbon:after {
  content:'';
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent #000;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px 5px;  
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:-10px;
}
```

This code works in other major browsers, but not in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">` is emulating IE 7 documents mode for IE 9 + 8 users. I don't see any advantage for doing such a thing as box-shadow isn't supported below IE9. You should use:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">` so that the newest version of IE is used no matter what, and so that if a user has the chrome frame installed it will be used instead of native IE.